# VB. NET:Several IF statements with Exit Sub or Nested IF statement without Exit Sub?

Tags: vb.net

Now I have a sub to validate a bunch of textboxes and combo boxes.

I previously used many IF statements to validate and pop up different messageboxes and Exit Sub in every IF statement.

But I heard that too many Exits will decrease the efficiency and they were not recommended to use. Instead, nested IF is better because it will let the process naturally go to the end.

Then I found out that if I use nested IF, it will be hard to read, since messageboxes are all separated from conditions.

I have no software development experience. So my question is: in the real projects, which style will you choose?

Comment: It is nonsense, don't believe everything you hear.  Not even here, measure.  Or reason it out, this is UI code.  You only have a human to keep happy.  You've got 100 million cpu cycles to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use what is more readable and what you agree with your team.

As for having many `Exits` decreasing performance - I don't know if that is true, but even if it was, I would expect it to be such a minimal amount to me a micro-micro-optimization. This is something you can easily test yourself - run both types of code in a loop (millions/billions of times) and measure how much time each took using the `StopWatch` class.

I personally find multiple returns easier to read in this specific case and it is my usual style.

Comment: +1 IMHO, in most cases, readability is more important than performance (unless the performance hit is particularly pronounce, which it shouldn't be in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use nested ifs for the processing and use Exit Sub/Function for pre-condition verification.  I've seen some developers throw Exit Sub/Function out the window and just the return keyword.

It depends on what your company's goals are with complexity.  The reason many use Exit Sub/Function statements is to reduce cyclomatic complexity by validating pre-conditions before the processing within subs and functions begin.  The idea here is to exit based on violation of pre-conditions, which would probably be else conditions in the nested ifs, which will dramatically reduce cyclomatic complexity thus increasing the maintainability of your code.

Just like with everything else there is a trade-off here based on readability.  If you have too many Exit Subs or Exit Functions, when calling that method through debugging it could get confusing on why the method was prematurely terminated and cause longer debugging times.

There has been a debate on the performance issues. But, I've never tested it.  I can say I haven't had any performance issues related to using Exit as opposed to using nested ifs.